# No display when self publish app install in a device firefox os

Tags: firefox-os

I am trying to install an application which is self-publishing. I successfully installed it, but when I open the application itself, no display shows. The icon of the application shows but the content of the app doesn't show anything.

How will I fix it?

This is my manifest.

**webapp file:**

```
{"name": "firefoxapp","description":"Example firefox application","launch_path": 

"app.html","version": "1","icons": {"512":

"/images/icon_512.png","128":"/images/icon_128.png"},"developer": {"name": "Systema 

Computer Solutions Corp.","url": "http://www.systemacorp.com"},"default_locale": "en"}
```

Comment: Try changing your launch path to /app.html . Also can you debug it with WebIDE?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the full path name of the front screen file in launch_path. If your file `app.html` is in the root folder of your app then try your modified manifest

```
{
  "name": "firefoxapp",
  "description":"Example firefox application",
  "launch_path": "/app.html","version": "1",
  "icons": {
            "512":"/images/icon_512.png",
            "128":"/images/icon_128.png"},
  "developer": {"name": "Systema Computer Solutions Corp.",
                 "url": "http://www.systemacorp.com"
               },
   "default_locale": "en"
}
```